# Streaming Average of Data

Tags: c

I have an incoming stream of analog values which I need to do some basic statistics on within a moving window of 1000 samples. I would rather not run through and sum up the entire window each time I add a sample (don't have the processing time). I wrote the code below which works, but when the index rolls back over to zero, I clearly need to do something so I don't have a big discontinuity in the data, but I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm missing.

```
void stats(double in, stat_s *out)
{
    static uint32_t index = 1;
    double sum = 0, sum1 = 0;
    double differential = 0;
    double newDSquared = 0;
    double newMean = 0;
    
    out->arr[index%wnd_sz] = in;//array index values cycle within window size

   if(index!=0) differential = (in - out->mean) / index;
    else {
        //Do something here since we rolled back to the head of the index
    }

   newMean = out->mean + differential;

   double dSquaredIncrement = (in - newMean) * (in - out->mean);
   if(dSquaredIncrement>0) newDSquared = out->dSquared + dSquaredIncrement;

   out->mean = newMean;
    out->dSquared = newDSquared;
    if(index!=0) out->variance = out->dSquared / index;
    
    out->std_dev = sqrt(out->variance);

    out->max = out->mean + out->std_dev;
    out->min = out->mean - out->std_dev;    

    //prevent overflow for long running sessions.
    if(index < 3*wnd_sz) index++;
    else {
        index = 0;
    }
}
```

When running the data looks like this:

[image: Sample data output]

You can see there's a big jump on the last waveform when the index reset to 0.

Comment: Why not use a ring-buffer type approach for a rolling window?

Comment: How would you approach that without having the sum up the values in the buffer each pass through?

Comment: For a sliding window you could do some fancy math to drop one value and add another, but it's probably quicker to just spin through and add them all up.

Comment: Before writing a new value, subtract the one that will be overwritten and add the new one?

Comment: I was thinking the same. That works for the mean, but not the variance which relies on the index

Comment: I'm not quite sure why the variance depends on the index. Shouldn't it depend on the number of values that contribute to `dSquared`? Also, currently, it looks like `dSquared` does not depend on the window size. Is that intentional?

Comment: Hmmm... dSquared depends on all of the values. Maybe once the buffer is initially full, that's just always 3 x wnd_sz?

Comment: But why would `dSquared` depend on values that are no longer in the buffer? If that's really what you want, why reset `index`? Your comment says it's to "prevent overflow", but surely you don't need to compute the variance over 2^32 values, do you? Even if you did, you can just change the type of `index` to have 64 or more bits...

Comment: Thought more about this... you're right. It only depends on the values that are still in the buffer. I'm working on the solution right now. Will post as an answer when I've tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured this out myself. @Nelfeal's comment about only needing the number of values I am basing the current calculation on is what I was missing. Here's the two functions that make this work:

First is the circular buffer:

```
double append(double in) {
    double poppedValue = 0;
    if (out.elements == wnd_sz) {
        poppedValue = out.arr[out.count];
    } else {
        out.elements++;
    }
        out.arr[out.count] = in;
        out.count = (out.count+1) % wnd_sz;
        return poppedValue;
}
```

Second is the actual stats work. This needed to broken into three states:

1. The initiation with no data in the buffer
2. The buffer has data but isn't full
3. The buffer is full

```
void stats(double in)
{
    //append element to circular buffer
    double poppedValue = append(in); //append process should return popped value or null if not full, also update out->count

    if (emptyBuffer) { //Buffer not full yet
        // initialize when the first value is added
        out.mean = in;
        out.dSquared = 0;
        emptyBuffer = false;
        out.std_dev = sqrt(out.dSquared/out.count);
        out.max = out.mean + out.std_dev;
        out.min = out.mean - out.std_dev; 
    } 
    
    if (!emptyBuffer && out.elements < wnd_sz) {
        // if the buffer is not full yet, use standard Welford method
        double meanIncrement = (in - out.mean) / out.count;
        double newMean = out.mean + meanIncrement;
        double dSquaredIncrement = (in - newMean);
        dSquaredIncrement *= (in - out.mean);
        double newDSquared = out.dSquared + dSquaredIncrement;
        out.mean = newMean;
        out.dSquared = newDSquared;
        out.std_dev = sqrt(out.dSquared/out.count);
        out.max = out.mean + out.std_dev;
        out.min = out.mean - out.std_dev; 
    } else {
        // once the buffer is full, adjust Welford Method for window size
        double meanIncrement = (in - poppedValue);
        meanIncrement /= 100.0;
        double newMean = out.mean + meanIncrement;
        double dSquaredIncrement = (in - poppedValue);
        dSquaredIncrement *= (in - newMean + poppedValue - out.mean);
        double newDSquared = out.dSquared + dSquaredIncrement;
        out.mean = newMean;
        out.dSquared = newDSquared;
        out.std_dev = sqrt(out.dSquared/wnd_sz);
        out.max = out.mean + out.std_dev;
        out.min = out.mean - out.std_dev; 
    }
}
```